# VirtualBox FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE

Tags: virtualbox, vhd

I have just took a back up of my windows PC, in the backup folder I can see a VHD file, I thought to run this with VirtualBox, but I the boot failure message. I suspect there is not boot information in the partition, if this is correct is there anyway to boot this file via VirtualBox.

Sorry, I have very min. knowledge about virtualization.

Comment: You can fix it with Startup Repair. Mark the partition active and then let startup repair do its thing.

Comment: I want it to get booted in VirtualBox, will startup repair work in this scenario....

Comment: It should. Startup repair should work in a virtual machine the same way it works on a physical machine.

Answer (score 50):

Enable `EFI`:

Settings `->` System `->` Motherboard

OR

> vboxmanage modifyvm *vmname* --firmware efi

Comment: Great answer, that helped me setting up the free virtual machines for testing Edge browser from microsoft site

Comment: @kabomi Me too! It's a great answer.

Comment: Did not work for me. After running the vboxmanage command, my machine boots into a UEFI setup utility of some kind.