# VirtualBox Ubuntu FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox

I am trying to boot Ubuntu inside Win 10 by raw disk access. [Ubuntu is located in a portion inside an external SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oD48.png). I followed the instructions from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box), everything went well, except when I start the virtual machine it throws me `FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE`. I had no idea what is going on, then I found this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/493858/virtualbox-fatal-int18-boot-failure), and the answer is to enable EFI, I also tried but had no avail.

What it [returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4iMA.png) after enabling EFI.

The vmdk file:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=e7fa4099
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="partitionedDevice"

# Extent description
RW 63 FLAT "raw-0-pt.vmdk" 0
RW 1985 ZERO 
RW 845699072 ZERO 
RW 131067904 FLAT "\\.\PhysicalDrive2" 845701120
RW 4096 ZERO 

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.uuid.image="a5265627-11cf-43ae-af17-18f88244f58e"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
```

I have been dealing with it for half a day, hope someone is able to answer

Comment: Probably a shot in the dark, but: did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: Still not, any idea?

Comment: I actually managed to fix it after my last comment. In my case, it was that the Ubuntu partition itself was not bootable. I had to create and mount 2 raw disk VMDKs, one for my main/default/Windows drive, and one for my Ubuntu partition, to be able to boot Ubuntu using grub.